# Update httpd.conf with virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I have a webserver with an old config (but a recent 2.4.6 apache).
Basically everything is in the 20 year old httpd.conf file, but I have some tools that complain that I need to define a virtual host. So I guess that means I must move some configs from `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mysite.conf` and add something wrapped in `<VirtualHost *:80>` there. It's probably not very complicated but I did a few tries without success.

The current config is short (slightly simplified and comments removed):

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/MySite/www/"
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: I don't see any `<VirtualHost>` in there, and I don't see any errors either.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to convert it to use <VirtualHost>, but I'm not sure which commands go inside.